# Identifying closest line segments of a quadrilateral which are perpendicular to a point

Tags: python, geometry, triangulation

**The Problem**

Apologies for incorrect formatting. This is my first post.
I have a quadrilateral with up to 5 pts per side (3 unique per side, four corners) [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkONq.png). When I click the cursor inside the polygon, I need to identify the line segments (north/south and east/west) that are closest to the point **while** being constrained by perpendicular lines at the start and end of each segment.
[Points A and B represent the segment end and beginning points. Point C is the selected point. The grey lines represent the "constraints" that Point C cannot be beyond.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbX8G.png)

[A visualization of what the end result looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUroi.png)

**What I've Tried**
As shown by the visualization, I've been able to write code for this, but it's very long and bulky.
If it were just finding the closest line segment, I'd be done. But the constraints add a complication.

My methodology is:

1. Segregate the data into four lists, the right side, left side, up side, and down side
2. Generates parallel lines for each segment. These lines must pass through the point and record the distance between the segment and the parallel line. [Shown here, the original segments and the parallel segments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hwDE.png) This gives the distance to determine left/right and up/down points.
3. For each segment, generate perpendicular lines at the beginning and end points.
4. Detects if the point is between those perpendicular lines (there can only be one valid segment for each side) [Example showing the point constrained by two parallel lines.  The right/left segments must be #12 or #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjLzT.png)
5. The recorded distances in #2 determine if left or right, up or down. Those sides are removed from #5. [Final result showing correct line segments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUnXG.png)

**Code**

The issue isn't the code, but that I'm sure there's an easier way out there to do this either in shapely or a geometry library. Does anyone know where to start looking?

Slightly related: Is there a decent way to figure out which points make up the corners of the shape?

Comment: Is side subdivision always symmetric, and every side is divided by N equal parts? Is quadrilateral always rectangle or square?

Comment: Thanks for the response. For clarification, this is for US township and range surveys. Each full square is supposed to be 1 mile on a side, so divided into 1/4 mile sections. Obviously, it doesn't end up being precise. Ideally, it should be four segments to a side, but there are some exceptions, but I can already deal with that. Just assume there's 4 segments to a side.

Since it's supposed to be a mile on each side, it should end up being roughly a square.

Answer (score 0):

For square:
Calculate coordinates in square local system:

```
tx = (x - left) / (right - left)
ty = (y - bottom) / (top - bottom)
left = (tx < 0.5)   #if tx < 0.5, then left side is close, otherwise right
bottom = (ty < 0.5)  #if ty < 0.5 then bottom side is close, otherwise top
```

Now detect order of proper segment in row/column (assuming N segments per side, for your example N=4)

```
xseg = int (tx * N)
yseg = int (ty * N)
```

now combine left/right and segment indices to get segments ID's according your clocwisr numeration:

```
if left:
   vert_seg = 1 + yseg
else:
   vert_seg = 3 * N - yseg

if bottom:
   horiz_seg = 4 * N - xseg
else:
   horiz_seg = N + 1 + xseg
```

Comment: This works only when the line segments are either perfectly horizontal or vertical, right?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it is needed to calculate position of perpendicular projection of point onto edge